# How to correctly affect multiple css properties in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

Below is an example of how I currently would affect two css properties for the same div in jquery:

```
$('#mydiv').css("width",myvar+"px");
$('#mydiv').css("margin-left",myvar+"px");
```

I don't believe this to be the most efficient method as it requires two lines of code for one div, can somebody please show me a more susinct (tidier) method of writing the same thing?

Comment: If myvar is a constant, then you can just add a class to myDiv and define the css in your stylesheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.css( properties )](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties)

> properties Type: PlainObject An object of property-value pairs to set.

```
$('#mydiv').css({
    "width": myvar + "px",
    "margin-left": myvar + "px"
});
```

---

Or you can add class to the element.

Comment: + "px" is not necessary, jQuery will assume it's pixels if you don't specify it

Comment: @JonasGrumann: Amusingly, I was just checking the docs to see if that was the case, because someone else mentioned it a couple of months back, and came back and saw your comment. I don't see that anywhere in the docs, is it *documented* behavior?

Comment: Wrong place in doc. Look down at `.css(properties)`. It says: `properties Type: PlainObject An object of property-value pairs to set.`

Comment: I think I've read it in some version's changelog, not really the doc. I guess they didn't mention it to avoid confusion. In the annotated source http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/11-css.html you can see if ( type === "number" && !jQuery.cssNumber[ origName ] ) {
        value += "px";
      }

Comment: @T.J.Crowder They talk about it in `animate()` relative DOC, regarding object of CSS properties: `Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.`. I hope this is relevant here too

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object instead:

```
$('#mydiv').css(
  { 
    'width': myvar + 'px',
    'margin-left': myvar + 'px'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this syntax (css properties)](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties).  Personally I prefer to use the javascript property syntax

```
$('#mydiv').css({
    width: myvar,
    marginLeft:  myvar
});
```

**Edit**: per the comment made on Tushar Gupta's answer, I've removed the `+ 'px'`.  Apparently you don't need that at least with the latest jQuery build. http://jsfiddle.net/75cMM/